# Printing values stored in enum data type

Tags: c

I am getting an error while printing enum data type, stating incompatible integer to point conversion passing int to parameter of type constant char.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   enum Company { GOOGLE, FACEBOOK, XEROX, YAHOO, EBAY, MICROSOFT};
   enum Company a = XEROX;
   enum Company b = GOOGLE;
   enum Company c = EBAY;
   printf('%c\n',a);
   printf('%d\n',b);
   printf('%d\n',c);
   return 0;
}
```

I was expecting a number, but it says its unable to print a multi-character constant.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Copy and paste the texts here in proper format. and don't tag irrelevant languages and add related flags

Comment: Where the code says `printf('%c\n',a);`, what do you think this means? Specifically, what do you think the `c` means? Where the code says `printf('%d\n',b);`, what do you think this means? Specifically, what do you think the `d` means? Are `a` and `b` of the same type? Is there a reason to use a different format string for each value? Aside from that: what do you think is the meaning of single quotes and double quotes in C? Which should be used for a string literal, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of quotes: don't do this:

```
printf('%d\n', a);
```

Do this instead:

```
printf("%d\n", a);
```